# Flutter to native- Calling native android or ios screen as a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I got a requirement to use the natively developed screen as a form of widget in the flutter code.
say i have a screen where half of the screen contains google-map for some height and rest of the design includes some other widgets. Here i want the google-map widget-a natively developed screen in the flutter as a widget(not as a screen directly but as a form of widget).
I want to know whether it is possible to do this way or not if yes how can we achieve this if anyone have any resources or links please share , it would be helpful to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please care to check official docs https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-views

Comment: Thank you! @ProblematicDude i will check this.

Comment: I have gone through with the documentation. It would be great if u could share any example with the platform-views .thanks.@ProblematicDude

Comment: How to pass our own layout and Activity instead of TextView. @ProblematicDude please help me out.I have a MapActivity.java and its own layout design i want to return this instead of TextView.